# Where can I get access to Google Play search data?

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know of a way to extract Google Play data?  Such as downloads, searches, search results ...  I was hoping there was some way I could request the data from google.  There seems to be quite a few websites that do analytics on it, so I was curious if anyone has experience in extracting the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official API or way to get data from Google Play.

Certain websites scrape data from the Google Play website using scripts, but this is not a guaranteed way to get the data.

Google Play's web site patterns often change and scraping data like this is generally a bad idea. Google will likely block most attempts - at least if they're obvious.

As a developer, you have the option of downloading statistics on your own applications, but that's it.

Also... This is hardly a programming question. Seems fairly off topic.

Comment: thanks for the response, would you suggest another more appropriate location to ask this question?

Comment: You could ask Google. They'll give you the same answer, though.